# How to create single executable jar file including all main and test packages including resource files

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

[image: I have a maven project structure as below:-]

TestNG - 7.3.0

Plugins used - maven-surefire-plugin maven-assembly-plugin

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG(); 
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/xmlFiles/testng12.xml";
    suites.add(fileName);
    testng.setTestSuites(suites); 
    testng.run();
}
```

I would like to create an executable jar file with all package like main , test packages including resources folder. maven-assembly-plugin only takes main package.

Comment: test packages are usually not part of the jar. They are only meant to be run during the build. Why do you want to have them inside the jar?

Comment: Hey, It is a requirement by the client who just wants to trigger a jar file and it should run tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no TestNG library added.

Comment: It is added in POM.xml as a dependency.